# How to make a button clicked by default in React

Tags: reactjs, button, default-value

I'm working at a ToDo app and I managed to make a menu section with two buttons switching between the app section. The problem is that when it's first opened the 'About me' button should be clicked by default, because this is the dafault path in Router. But I can't make it clicked by default, I tried different ways but nothing works. When I open the app, neither button is clicked. Could someone help me with this?

This is the code:

```
const App = () => {
  const buttons = ["Дела", "Обо мне"];
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className={styles.menu}>
          <ul className={styles.nav}>
            {buttons.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (clicked === index) {
                      setClicked();
                    }
                    if (!clicked) {
                      setClicked(this.index);
                    } else {
                      setClicked(index);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  <NavLink to={`/buttons/${index}`}>
                    {
                      <button
                        className={classnames({
                          [styles.button]: true,
                          [styles.selected]: clicked === index
                        })}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    }
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="buttons" element={<App buttons={buttons} />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
          <Route path=":button/0" element={<Todo />} />
          <Route path=":button/1" element={<About />} />
          <Route />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried to store default clicked value in useState somehow to make it work, but it didn't help. Probably I misunderstand something and do it wrong.

Comment: Why are you putting buttons in links to start with? What does it mean to you for a button to be clicked as a _state_, rather than an _action_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I'm new to react, don't I have to link buttons to app sections? I thought switching wouldn't work without it

Comment: I think you want a link styled based on the active class, but it's really unclear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure about how to style a link and set one of them selected by default. I tried to make a button clicked by default with this line: if (!clicked) {      setClicked(this.index), but it's not working.

Comment: That's exactly what a NavLink _already does_: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Comment: Forget about clicking. It doesn't matter if the user uses a pointer event or keyboard or a voice command to modify the state of your app. What is it that clicking does to items? It looks to me like it makes an item ***active***. And it also looks to me like only one item can be active at one time. So you probably want to set a piece of state holding the id of the currently active Item (which you can instantiate to the one you want active at first). And on some type of user interactions you set that state to another item's id, when you want to change the currently active item.

Comment: Yeah,  buttons can't be nested in anchors. That's invalid HTML and a violation of their semantic intent.

Comment: I'm just learning react, I began to do it at an online course, but it suddenly closed and now I want to finish the app myself. I found this way to link and route mapped buttons somewhere online. I thought it was ok because the code is working and there are no errors in console. Is this wrong? Could you show me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) accepts an argument with the initial state that you want.

If I understand correctly, `clicked` stores the index of the button which is clicked. So you can give it `0` to make the 1st button start as clicked, or `1` to make the second button start as clicked:

```js
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(1);
```